# Distribute divs randomly yet evenly without overlap, in a larger div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to distribute smaller divs of varying widths and heights in a larger div, similar to the layouts shown in these [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4ZGm.jpg). I will not have more than 4 smaller divs in one full page div. Depending on the size, a single full page container could have 2-4 divs, with an average of 3. 
Currently, I am able to have smaller containers in a bigger container without any overlap but the smaller divs cluster as noticed [here](https://codepen.io/mantrarush/pen/MEmjog).

```
function getRandomColor() {
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += (Math.random() * 16 | 0).toString(16);
        }
        return color;
    }

    function Point(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    function Rectangle(p1, p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    Rectangle.prototype.isInside = function (r) {
        function check(a, b) {
            return (
                a.p1.x <= b.p1.x && b.p1.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p1.y && b.p1.y <= a.p2.y ||
                a.p1.x <= b.p2.x && b.p2.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p2.y && b.p2.y <= a.p2.y ||
                a.p1.x <= b.p2.x && b.p2.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p1.y && b.p1.y <= a.p2.y ||
                a.p1.x <= b.p1.x && b.p1.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p2.y && b.p2.y <= a.p2.y
            );
        }
        return check(this, r) || check(r, this);
    }

function generateRectangles() {
    function genPoint() { return Math.random() * 300 | 0; }
    function genSize() { return 50 + Math.random() * 150 | 0; }

    var rectangles = [],
        r, sizea, sizeb, x, y, isInside, i, counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        do {
            counter++;
            x = genPoint();
            y = genPoint();
            sizea = genSize();
            sizeb = genSize();
            r = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Point(x + sizea, y + sizeb));
            isInside = rectangles.some(function (a) {
                return a.isInside(r);
            });
        } while (isInside && counter < 1000);
        counter < 1000 && rectangles.push(r);
    }
    return rectangles;
}

function drawRectangles(rectangles) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    rectangles.forEach(function (a) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeRect(a.p1.x + 0.5, a.p1.y + 0.5, a.p2.x - a.p1.x - 1, a.p2.y - a.p1.y - 1);
        ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
        ctx.fillRect(a.p1.x + 0.5, a.p1.y + 0.5, a.p2.x - a.p1.x - 1, a.p2.y - a.p1.y - 1);
    });
}

var rectangles = generateRectangles();
drawRectangles(rectangles);
```

Comment: I see overlapping rectangles...

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your problem here.  Is it that your rectangles are overlapping or that they are grouped or what?  If you look at the code it makes sense you could have them clustered based on the fact that they are being randomly generated.  If you are that concerned about overlap a cheap fix would be to limit the width of a rectangle to 25% and then let them go from 0 to max height in the Y direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "clustering"?  That they are all generated in close proximity?  You are generating `x` position `<= 300` but showing them inside a box `1000` wide...

Comment: I think as long as you left everything to random, clustering will happen. How about  remembering the x,y,width,height of each generated rectangle and use it for the next iteration of randomizing?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan - Whoops, I didn't see any, in first dozen of times I ran it. I will have to check.

Comment: `counter` mightve hit 1000

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - Currently, my rectangles are not overlapping, and I want to distribute them farther away from each other rather than see them cluster next to each other. I don't know what code should I add to keep the smaller divs away from each other as much as possible, while avoiding overlap. I want to distribute the divs evenly across the canvas.

Comment: So if you want to keep the smaller divs further away then you'll need to store the information of each div created and ensure the distance between the rectangles is satisfactory.